# Angular 2/4 not work correctly in first load

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have error when using router.navigate in angular 4, when route to other page, this page is not load correctly after refresh page.

I'm using **angular2-color-picker**

First time load page, color box is just text.
[image: First time load page]

And after refresh, it had background color.
[image]

> Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Add more code or create plunker. without code difficult understand your problem

Comment: Because you must use hash strategy. In your module, do this : `RouterModule.forRoot(yourRoutes, { useHash: true })`

Comment: @trichetriche I had add this in app.routing.ts but dont work export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true });

Answer (score 0):

Add to your app.module  in providers

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from  '@angular/common';


@NgModule({  
 ...
 providers: [ 
 {
  provide: LocationStrategy,
  useClass: HashLocationStrategy
 }]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```